# Referring to John's Serenity BDD book, can a @Test annotation encompass a complete scenario, as part of running SerenityRunner.class?

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity-js

I am referring to John's Serenity bdd book @ https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/step-libraries.html. Very in the beginning, John seem to be enclosing a set of @given @when @then step definitions inside a method, which is annotated with a tag **@Test**.

```
@Test
public void members_should_start_with_Bronze_status() {
        // GIVEN
        tracy.joins_the_frequent_flyer_program();
        // THEN
        tracy.should_have_a_status_of(Bronze);
    }
```

1.How would you choose the name of the method ? From the step line describing **Scenario:keyword?**

2.Would this be possible only when you use **@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)** annotation just before declaration of StepDefinition class?

3.How about if you were using `@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)` instead?
What is the best place of declaring this annotation ? In the TestRunner.java file or as you have shown in side the stepdefinition class file ?

4.What is the role of serenity.properties at the root of the project Vs. TestRunner.java file ? Can we use exclusively one instead of both ?

*SORRY FOR THESE MANY QUESTIONS.* On behalf of JUnit-Cucumber-Serenity Test Developers,
I am saying this
**"We are struggling, not having a definitive documentation"**.

I know it is in the nature of the beast. Because Serenity can be used in conjunction with all the above
technologies and a single, simple answer would be difficult.

BTW, I looked at the John's starter project for **Serenity-junit-starter-master** project([Serenity-junit-starter](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-junit-starter.)) which to most extent illustrates his book, I could not locate the feature file anywhere. Connecting dots between feature file and the Steps document would have given much insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“// GIVEN” etc are just comments; they are unrelated to Cucumber. You can run Serenity with JUnit, Cucumber or JBehave, but most of the book (currently) focuses on pure JUnit implementations.

Comment: It is what it is though ! I was expecting one way or the other to connect feature file and it's step definitions inside this **@Test** annotation and the component methods enclosed inside the **@Test** method are implementing the **@Given@When@Then** steps.
May be one day, it would be possible. :)